# PostgreSQL - Converting a string with quotes to different string using case?

Tags: sql, json, string, postgresql, metabase

So hopefully this isn't a super difficult question. I've looked around but haven't been able to find an answer. Basically I have a table in a READ-ONLY db that I'm trying to use a case statement to convert a column that stores JSON values (I think?) to something more visually pleasing.

The table shows Emails, and the Status of whether or not they're subscribed to the mailing list.

[EXAMPLE HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c8f9612c0069cc7916b405dec9355ccd)

Basically my query looks something like this

```
select
    f.data as "Email",
    (
     case f.status
        when '{"value":true}' then 'Yes'
        when '{"value":false}' then 'No'
        else NULL
     end
     ) as "Subscribed"
from fields f
```

When I run this in my example page it works just fine when set to POSTGRES 11 but when I run it on Metabase, I get an error "ERROR: operator does not exist: json = unknown" and I'm stumped on how to proceed.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The title says MySQL, but in the question you say PostGres. Which database are you actually using?

Comment: `json = unknown` doesn't appear anywhere in the query. The problem must be related to how you're using Metabase.

Comment: Sorry it's PostgreSQL I've been bouncing between a few today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means `f.status` is of type `json` and you're trying to compare it to a string, which doesn't work.

You can try the following instead (related [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)):

```
case f.status->>'value'
    when 'true' then 'Yes'
    when 'false' then 'No'
end
as "Subscribed"
```